# Access Api Gateway from Lambda under VPC

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, vpc

I need to fetch some data from `ApiGateway` endpoint and then based on response store this data in database.

I created simple `Lambda` function that just fetch data from `ApiGateway` endpoint and print it in console. My first Lambda function did not have any `VPC` configuration and fetch operation worked like a charm.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

exports.handler = async () => {
  const data = await fetch("https://<<ag-api-key>>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/data");
  const response = await data.json();
  console.log(data, response);
}
```

As I need to store data received from endpoint into database which run under VPC I decided to put Lambda in same VPC(this vpc has configured Internet Gateways and other stuff to have access to internet).
As a result `fetch` operation start to fail with `403` response code and `{"message":"Forbidden"}` response body.

Api Gateway resource does not have any custom domain configuration and maintained by other team so I do not have direct access to its configuration

May be anyone can suggest how I can fix this

Answer (score 1):

1. Security Groups, check if port 443 is open
2. Check your CORS Setting on API Gateway.
3. Try Hitting the API Gateway with Postman/Fiddler, or any other testing tool to make sure your API Gateway is online and you can get the response you want.
4. If you are using a Private API-Gateway (Sounds like you are using public looking at the URL) you will need some header data and different URL. I can guide you through it if needed. I would avoid private API gateway if I were you.

Let me know if any of that helps. I have ran into that issue many times in different situations.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but my VPC has no internet access. When I create an endpoint to it, I get a Forbidden response If private DNS is flagged. If I don't flag it, I get a timeout response. I wonder what did you guys make to sort it out. Thanks

Comment: @MatheusMaximo hi Matheus, I am facing with the same issue, I wonder how did you fix your issue?

Comment: @HalilİbrahimÖzdoğan there's a long list of settings to follow and set up the Lambda for that. You can find it here: https://blog.theodo.com/2020/01/internet-access-to-lambda-in-vpc/